# How to raise error in bash if a dir does not match certain permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions

How can I raise an error in bash if a directory at some path does not match the below permissions?

```
u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rwX
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `[ 777 -eq $(($(stat --format "%a" "$dir_path" ))) ] || exit 1`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `stat` command

```bash
#! /bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
PERM=$(stat --format "%A" "$FILENAME")
echo "$FILENAME" "$PERM"

u=${PERM:1:3}
g=${PERM:4:3}
o=${PERM:7:3}

echo "$u" "$g" "$o"
```

Comment: after you have obtained access rights, you can force the exit from the program by comparing with your conditions